# What do we know about the set of all games having Nash equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

Let us denote $G$ set of all games (of some particular type), and then consider  $N = \{ g \in G | \mbox{game $g$ admits (mixed) Nash equilibrium} \}$. I want to ask you for some good source describing the properties of set $N$ (is it convex, closed, what geometry does it have etc). Or rather, under wich additional conditions is $N$ convex, etc.

Particularly, let us consider the case of $G$ being the set of (possibly infinite) two-player zero-sum games that are symmetric, and $N$ being subset of those games admitting mixed Nash equilibrium. What are the properties of $N$ then?

Reacting to the comment of Yanko, by a convex combination of two games $G_1 = (S_i, u_i)_{i \in I}$ and $G_2 = (S_i, v_i)_{i \in I}$ having the same set of pure strategies I mean simply a game $H = (S_i, \lambda u_i + (1-\lambda) v_i )_{i \in I}$, i.e. a game with convex combination of their pay-off functions.

Thank you, cheers, Mirek

Comment: How do you define a convex combination of games? What topology do you consider on $N$?

Comment: Well, Nash's own [existence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_equilibrium#Nash's_Existence_Theorem) ought to get you started, at least.

Comment: Dear Yanko, I know I am not totally precise, I would actually go with any topology giving some positive answers, I found no results in this respect.

Comment: Hello Arthur, I am not sure that this will be of much help. Sure, one can take any existence theorem for NE, and describe the conditions under which its particular assumptions are conserved (say, continuity of the respective pay-off functions is conserved under convex combination of two continuous games). Thus, however, we would describe properties only of some subset of $N$.